# Pkg-config script could not be found

Tags: macos, homebrew, pkg-config

I am trying to install some software, but I keep receiving the error:

```
configure: error: The pkg-config script could not be found or is too old.  Make sure it
is in your PATH or set the PKG_CONFIG environment variable to the full
path to pkg-config.
```

I just installed the `brew` command, and tried to use it to install pkg-config. It says that it is already installed.

I made sure that it is in the path via `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/pkg-config`.

Also, trying to install glib, it says I am missing libfft. I used `brew install libfft` to install this missing package. However, I still get a message stating that it is not there. This is a new mac, so perhaps things are not going in the proper directories?

Any help would be appreciated, as I am beyond lost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what formula you are trying to install, but the real problem may be that whatever you are trying to install isn't marked as "depending on" pkg-config.   It may need this line:

`depends_on "pkg-config" => :build`

Comment: Not only is the question off topic, it's 10 years old and Bob Dole is dead.